# Multiple array data post through Angular JS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

Here is the part of the view in the HTML page of through this a user can fill the data and send it to api

[image]

in the form there is three parameter will pass in a single array, day. fromtime and to-time. how to pass these three parameter in a single array... in jSON in angular JS, My code is not working here is the code. **i want to also now how to send data in this format in HTML/Angular view side?**

My (i thought it would work) Angular Js code

```
  $scope.schedule = [];
                $scope.schedule[0] = $scope.data1.day;
                $scope.schedule[1] = $scope.data1.from_time;
                $scope.schedule[2] = $scope.data1.to_time;

            var dataParam =  {

                                "Schedule":[$scope.data1.schedule]

                              }
         console.log(angular.toJson(dataParam));
```

HTML code

```
<tr>
                                            <th  scope="col"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" ng-model="data.checkbox1"></th>
                                            <td ng-model="data1.day">Sunday</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                                <select  id="user_time_zone" ng-disabled="!data.checkbox1" class="form-control form-group" value="Schedule" name="user_time_zone">
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="" >00</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="01" >01</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="02" >02</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="o3" >03</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="04" >04</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="05" >05</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="06" >06</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="07" >07</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="08" >08</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="09" >09</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="10" >10</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="11" >11</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="12" >12</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="13" >13</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="14" >14</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="15" >15</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="16" >16</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="17" >17</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="18" >18</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="19" >19</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="20" >20</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="21" >21</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="22" >22</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="23" >23</option>
                                                </select>

                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                                     <select  id="user_time_zone" ng-disabled="!data.checkbox1" class="form-control  form-group" value="Schedule" name="user_time_zone">
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="" >00</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="05" >05</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="10" >10</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="15" >15</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="20" >20</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="25" >25</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="30" >30</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="35" >35</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="40" >40</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="45" >45</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="50" >50</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="55" >55</option>
                                                    </select>

                                                </div>  
                                            </td>
                                            <td><b>:</b></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                                <select  id="user_time_zone" ng-disabled="!data.checkbox1" class="form-control  form-group" value="Schedule" name="user_time_zone">
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="" >00</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="01" >01</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="02" >02</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="o3" >03</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="04" >04</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="05" >05</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="06" >06</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="07" >07</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="08" >08</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="09" >09</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="10" >10</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="11" >11</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="12" >12</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="13" >13</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="14" >14</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="15" >15</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="16" >16</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="17" >17</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="18" >18</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="19" >19</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="20" >20</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="21" >21</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="22" >22</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="23" >23</option>
                                                </select>

                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div  class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                                     <select  id="user_time_zone" ng-disabled="!data.checkbox1" class="form-control  form-group" value="Schedule" name="user_time_zone">
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="" >00</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="05" >05</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="10" >10</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="15" >15</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="20" >20</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="25" >25</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="30" >30</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="35" >35</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="40" >40</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="45" >45</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="50" >50</option>
                                                    <option id="optionspec" value="55" >55</option>
                                                    </select>

                                                </div>
                                            </td>



                                            <td>
                                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Add Break" id="btn" ng-disabled="!data.checkbox1">
                                            </td>
                                           </tr>
```

A small snippet of java code

```
public class Schedule {
private String Working_day;
private List<String> Working_from;
private List<String> working_to; 

........ }
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass this as array?

Comment: are you sure that both [$scope.data1.schedule] and $scope.schedule are having the same data. here i dont see anything like $scope.data1.schedule bieng assigned some value.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var dataParam =  {"Schedule":[$scope.data1.schedule]} with
var dataParam =  {"Schedule":$scope.schedule}
```

Comment: can you plz tell me how to send the data through html in this format beacuse we can only give one array with different parameter but what if i have to monday data also?